# What does deleting a pointer mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Is deleting a pointer same as freeing a pointer (that allocates the memory)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deleting a pointer (or deleting what it points to, alternatively) means

```
delete p;
delete[] p; // for arrays
```

`p` was allocated prior to that statement like

```
p = new type;
```

It may also refer to using other ways of dynamic memory management, like `free`

```
free(p);
```

which was previously allocated using `malloc` or `calloc`

```
p = malloc(size);
```

The latter is more often referred to as "freeing", while the former is more often called "deleting". `delete` is used for classes with a destructor since `delete` will call the destructor in addition to freeing the memory. `free` (and `malloc`, `calloc` etc) is used for basic types, but in C++ `new` and `delete` can be used for them likewise, so there isn't much reason to use `malloc` in C++, except for compatibility reasons.

Comment: so it all brings back to the difference between in memory management of new/delete and free/malloc ?

Comment: a pointer pointing to NULL and a 'deleted' pointer are same or different?

Comment: @ashish, yes. malloc and free do only care about the memory, not about the type of what will be in it. `new` cares about the type and calls constructors if necessary, and it can also be extended to get memory from a different memory pool than the default (by writing your own `operator new` and `operator delete` respectively).

Comment: @ashish, changing a pointer's value to null is different from deleting it. The pointer will point to no object afterwards if you only set it to null, but the memory of the object it pointed to previously won't be freed. So in effect you will leak memory by doing that. First delete/free, and then set to null (don't let deleted pointers keep their old value - it will make you unable to test later whether the pointer points to allocated memory or not. That's bad).

Comment: @litb then what will happen if i try to delete a pointer pointing to null?

Comment: @ashish, nothing will happen. deleting a null pointer has no effect. See the C++ FAQ for more information about it: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html

Comment: Nothing. `delete 0` is defined to be a no-op.

Answer (score 11):

> You can't "delete" a pointer variable

Sure you can ;-)

```
int** p = new int*(new int(42));
delete *p;
delete p; // <--- deletes a pointer
```

But seriously, `delete` should really be called `delete_what_the_following_pointer_points_to`.

Comment: @piyukr No, `delete` calls the destructor before it releases the memory. `free` just releases the memory. Calling `free` on a pointer obtained from `new` causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `delete` is used to deallocate memory and call the destructor for the object involved.

It's common pratice to set pointer to `NULL` after deleting it to avoid having invalid pointers around:

```
Object *o = new Object();

// use object
delete o; // call o->~Object(), then releases memory
o = NULL;
```

When `new` and `delete` are used with standard C types in C++ source they behave like `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: +1, but technically the compiler calls the destructor, then releases the memory, in that order.

Comment: Yes, I didn't specify order.. my mistake, actually calling a destructor of a deallocated object doesn't make much sense..

Comment: The order comes from your comment following delete o; (should be reversed).

Answer (score 1):

You can't "delete" a pointer variable, only set their value to NULL (or 0).

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer - if Ashish meant a C pointer such as when defining "char *cpString". In C, we never free a pointer, but instead we free allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes deleting a pointer is the same as deallocating memory or freeing memory, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and it calls the appropriate destructor.

Comment: Well, no it isn't, since it calls the destructor while free does not!

Comment: Furthermore, there's no guarantee that "delete" and "free" work off the same heaps.  If you allocate something with "new" and then do a "free" on it, you may corrupt your heap and/or crash your program.  Likewise with the "malloc"/"delete" combo.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I was thinking of "free" in a more general, nonkeyword sense

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

But you have to be careful: if you allocate with `p = new sometype()` only then should you use `delete p`. If you allocate using `p = sometype[count]` always use `delete [] p`

And one more thing: you should never pair `malloc/delete` or `new/free`.